# Automatically translate plain text to clickable URLs in chat messages in angular application

Tags: angular

I am developing a chat feature for an angular application. I want to detect URLs in the text entered and show them as clickable links when sent.

I tried using

```
<div class="chatbox-text" ng-bind-html="chatbox-text | linky:'_blank'">{{ message.content }}</div>
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

My requirement is :

User1: www.example.com, clicks on send. It should be displayed as a clickable URL for User2.

Comment: please change the tag as this is not Angular, it is AngularJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using linky directive which seems like AngularJS library.

I would suggest that you use [linkify-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkify-it), works very well.

Edit : just noticed the question is tagged `angular` but code is AngularJS. If it is really Angular (as in 2+) use the library above and bind to `innerHTML`:

```
<div [innerHTML] = "msg | linkifyDirective | sanitizeHTML" ></div>
```

Note that I made up the directive names, that's just to send you in the direction. Or you can do without directives and linkify and sanitize message in function but that comes with performance cost.

If your project really is AngularJS, then please change the tag.

Comment: If that worked for you, please accept the answer to help others who find this question.

Comment: how do you import that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send message like http://example.com with http in the beginning? Because www.example.com is not link

Comment: Hi , Thank you .  Yes, it did not work that way too.

Answer (score 0):

What about this logic to show the text:

- split the input string in separated words
- create an array of Segments, where the segment has the attributes: value and isLink
- in the constructor of Segments check if the text is a link, starts with HTTP or www or any other rules
- in your template show each Segment as a span with a click event associated to it
- in the click event handler receive the Segment object if is link redirect to the link
- in the template assign a CSS class to show the span as a link if islink is true

Have fun!

Comment: Hi , Thank you very much. Will try